# How can I use PHP's built-in webserver with Symfony on Windows, with a specified hostname and nonstandard port?

Tags: php, symfony

EDIT: Sorry everyone, this isn't something you could have fixed!  The AppKernel class had been modified to change the cache directory, as below:

```
public function getCacheDir()
{
    if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']))
    {
        return $this->rootDir.'/cache/'.$this->environment.'/'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
    }
    else{
        return $this->rootDir.'/cache/'.$this->environment.'/default';
    }
 }
```

So not down to Symfony, or PHP, but a previous developer (presumably not on Windows!).  Thanks for all your help, +1s all round.

---

I'm hoping there's a simple answer to this, but right now I can't see it!

```
Windows 10
Symfony 2.8.11
PHP 5.5.9
```

For convenience, I'd like to use PHP's built-in webserver (via the Symfony Console) to run a Symfony (2.8) application, on a port other than 80.  I have a colleague successfully doing this, but he's using Linux, and I'm on Windows 10.  The issue is that, on anything other than the standard port 80, when Symfony builds its cache the port is appended to one of the directory names, with a colon, which is illegal in Windows filenames (although not elsewhere).  The cache build process fails, and the app doesn't run.

I'm starting the PHP server via Symfony's Console, like so:

```
php app/console server:run appname.local
```

The directory it's trying to build is:

```
C:\git\appname\app/cache/dev/appname.local:8000
```

And so I get the error:

```
RuntimeException in bootstrap.php.cache line 2763:
Unable to create the cache directory C:\git\appname\app/cache/dev/appname.local:8000)
```

I'd just use the standard port (this does work), but in fact I want to run several things at once, and they can't all be on 80.

Is there any way I can run a Symfony site on PHP's webserver, on Windows, on a non-standard port, in such a way that Symfony doesn't choke at the point of building the cache?  For clarity, I could change webserver, and I could change OS, but for the purposes of this question assume that those are fixed.  I'd prefer not to switch off the cache (it's slow enough as it is!) but that's an option if it would help.

EDIT: it seems like this works for at least some people, so there must be something different about my config.  Best bet is probably the PHP version, which is quite old (not for any particular reason, just laziness).

Comment: With xamp / wamp you can have virtual hosts to have many website without having port problem (like `mysite1.dev`, `mysite2.dev`).

Comment: Why do you have different directory separators? Did you launched `composer install` in the begining?

Comment: It's just how Symfony creates cache dirs, probably not ideal, but you could dig into the code where the cache is created and change it...

Comment: Where is this appname.local coming from?  Something in your hosts file maybe? Typically it would be an ip address.

Comment: @goto This is true, but I'd like to do it like this!

Comment: @Veve Not sure.  No I didn't, I cloned a repo and went from there.  That said, I don't think it's causing the issue (given that getting rid of the ":portnumber" lets things work).

Comment: @Brian True, but yuck!  I actually considered that, and might have tried it but I couldn't quite see where the path was coming from (I could see the getCacheDir function, but what was returned from it didn't seem to be correct).  I backed away, maintaining eye contact.

Comment: @Cerad Yes, hosts file.  The app currently effectively serves 3 sites from one codebase based on the hostname used in the browser, so I'm stuck with that.

Comment: Seems a bit bizarre.  I tried it on my windows 10 with several different ports and everything works as expected.  I have no idea why it would be trying to create another directory under cache/dev.  Mine certainly doesn't.  Install a fresh project and try it.  Did you fool around with the config or web files?

Comment: I think it might be the multiple hosts, possibly.  Normally the cache goes straight in the dev dir.  I admit I've never used the built-in server before now.  Thanks for trying!

Comment: Well okay.  I routinely have several servers running for several different projects.

Answer (score 3):

Symfony has a command to run a webserver (which uses the php built-in PHP server)

```
php bin/console server:start
```

This command will start the server on port 8000 (default config)

Have a look here for more information about available options : https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/built_in_web_server.html

Comment: You got me all excited there, but in fact that's what I'm using!  Although the Symfony Console has a command for starting it, it's actually handing off to the PHP server under the hood.  I'll make my question more clear.

Comment: @frumious using a fresh symfony 2.8.15 install with php 7.1 on windows 10, i got no error... http://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/869212Capture.png did you change something in the symfony config ? (as a side note, i don't have a `appname` directory in `app/cache`)

Comment: Thanks a lot for trying that, does seem like you're doing what I'm doing but with no error.  Oh, it's PHP 5.5.9, don't know if that would make a difference.  This is an inherited project, so I couldn't easily tell you exactly what's changed from default.

Answer (score 1):

to start the server on a particular port specify the port after the IP address from the command line. Using the IP address is useful too, because you can access from a different host.

For example, let's say you run `ipconfig /all` and you see your IPv$ address is `192.168.1.100`. Then you can run:

```
php bin/console server:start 192.168.1.100:8888
```

This starts [Symfony's built-in web server](http://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/built_in_web_server.html) on port `8888` on IP address `192.168.1.100`. So in a browser you can enter: http://192.168.1.100:8888/ where `/` is the route you want to access.

To stop the built-in server enter:

```
php bin console server:stop 192.168.1.100:8888
```

You'll see messages on the command line showing the stopping/starting of the built-in web server.

Comment: Thanks Alvin.  My problem is not starting the server, or configuring what IP and port it uses, but what Symfony does after that.

Comment: Hi frumious. Can you run `php bin/symfony_requirements` from the command line and see what that shows. The cache problem is weird, because the only thing I can think of is a permissions issue, but since this is a Windows system, that shouldn't happen.

Comment: No output, not sure what's meant to happen.  I've confirmed through debugging that it's trying to create a dir with : in it, and that Windows definitely doesn't like that...

Comment: Sorry, I just realized you are on 2.8. Try `php app/check.php` instead. See [this link](http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/reference/requirements.html). It should print out messages about anything that you might need to install/change. Also, are you using xampp or wamp, or something else?

Comment: In fact I found SymfonyRequirements.php, ran it, and got literally nothing out.  check.php gives me a couple of warnings (intl and PHP accelerator not installed), otherwise OK.

Comment: Those are just warnings, that sounds good. Why not create a fresh project like Cerad mentioned. I think that might be a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

As in my question edit, this was down to developer action rather than a Symfony or PHP issue to be solved by the community.

```
public function getCacheDir()
{
    if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']))
    {
        return $this->rootDir.'/cache/'.$this->environment.'/'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']; //KABOOM
    }
    else{
        return $this->rootDir.'/cache/'.$this->environment.'/default';
    }
}
```

Thanks for all your efforts!

Answer (score 0):

```
public function getCacheDir()
{
    if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']))
    {
        return str$this->rootDir.'/cache/'.$this->environment.'/'.str_replace(':','_', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
    }
    else{
        return $this->rootDir.'/cache/'.$this->environment.'/default';
    }
 }
```

a colon isnt a valid character for filesystem filename, so replace it with underscore.